# Google Web Tookit User extensions missing Spinner?

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

When I look at the example of the user extensions of GWT-Ext I saw the Spinner as a user extension:  http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo-ux/#spinner

When I download the library from http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ext-ux/downloads/list (I downloaded the latest build -- 0.3.0) it does not appear to contain the Spinner class.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thread discussing the Spinner. There are some download links at the bottom of the first post.

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16352